# Simple curiosity about relation between texture mapping and shader program using Opengl/GLSL

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl, texture-mapping, texture2d

I'm working on a small homemade 3D engine and more precisely on rendering optimization. Until here I developped a sort algorithm whose goal is to gather a maximum of geometry (meshes) which have in common the same material properties and same shader program into batches. This way I minimize the state changes (glBindXXX) and draw calls (glDrawXXX). So, if I have a scene composed by 10 boxes, all sharing the same texture and need to be rendered with the same shader program (for example including ADS lighting) so all the vertices of these meshes will be merged into a unique VBO, the texture will be bind just one time and one simple draw call only will be needed.

```
Scene description:

- 10 meshes (boxes) mapped with 'texture_1'

Pseudo-code (render):

shaderProgram_1->Bind()
{
     glActiveTexture(texture_1)
     DrawCall(render 10 meshes with 'texture_1')
}
```

But now I want to be sure one thing: Let's assume our scene is always composed by the same 10 boxes but this time 5 of them will be mapped with a different texture (not multi-texturing, just simple texture mapping).

```
Scene description:

- 5 boxes with 'texture_1'
- 5 boxes with 'texture_2'

Pseudo-code (render):

shaderProgram_1->Bind()
{
     glActiveTexture(texture_1)
     DrawCall(render 5 meshes with 'texture_1')
}
shaderProgram_2->Bind()
{
     glActiveTexture(texture_2)
     DrawCall(render 5 meshes with 'texture_2')
}
```

And my fragment shader has a unique declaration of sampler2D (the goal of my shader program is to render geometry with simple texture mapping and ADS lighting):

```
uniform sampler2D ColorSampler;
```

I want to be sure it's not possible to draw this scene with a unique draw call (like it was possible with my previous example (1 batch was needed)). It was possible because I used the same texture for the whole geometry. I think this time I will need 2 batches hence 2 draw calls and of course for the rendering of each batch I will bind the 'texture_1' and 'texture_2' before each draw call (one for the first 5 boxes and an other one for the 5 others).

To sum up, if all the meshes are mapped with a simple texture (simple texture mapping):

- 5 with a red texture (texture_red)
- 5 with a blue texture (texture_blue)

Is it possible to render the scene with a simple draw call? I don't think so because my pseudo code will look like this:

```
Pseudo-code:

shaderProgram->Bind()
{
     glActiveTexture(texture_blue)
     glActiveTexture(texture_red)
     DrawCall(render 10 meshes)
}
```

I think it's impossible to differentiate the 2 textures when my fragment shader has to compute the pixel color using a unique sampler2D uniform variable (simple texture mapping).

Here's my fragment shader:

```
#version 440

#define MAX_LIGHT_COUNT 1

/*
** Output color value.
*/
layout (location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;

/*
** Inputs.
*/
in vec3 Position;
in vec2 TexCoords;
in vec3 Normal;

/*
** Material uniforms.
*/
uniform MaterialBlock
{
    vec3 Ka, Kd, Ks;
    float Shininess;

}   MaterialInfos;

uniform sampler2D ColorSampler;

struct Light
{
    vec4 Position;
    vec3 La, Ld, Ls;
    float Kc, Kl, Kq;
};

uniform struct Light LightInfos[MAX_LIGHT_COUNT];

uniform unsigned int LightCount;

/*
** Light attenuation factor.
*/
float getLightAttenuationFactor(vec3 lightDir, Light light)
{
    float lightAtt = 0.0f;
    float dist = 0.0f;

    dist = length(lightDir);
    lightAtt = 1.0f / (light.Kc + (light.Kl * dist) + (light.Kq * pow(dist, 2)));
    return (lightAtt);
}

/*
** Basic phong shading.
*/
vec3 Basic_Phong_Shading(vec3 normalDir, vec3 lightDir, vec3 viewDir, int idx)
{
    vec3 Specular = vec3(0.0f);

    float lambertTerm = max(dot(lightDir, normalDir), 0.0f);

    vec3 Ambient = LightInfos[idx].La * MaterialInfos.Ka;
    vec3 Diffuse = LightInfos[idx].Ld * MaterialInfos.Kd * lambertTerm;

    if (lambertTerm > 0.0f)
    {
        vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normalDir);
        Specular = LightInfos[idx].Ls * MaterialInfos.Ks * pow(max(dot(reflectDir, viewDir), 0.0f), MaterialInfos.Shininess);
    }
    return (Ambient + Diffuse + Specular);
}

/*
** Fragment shader entry point.
*/
void main(void)
{
    vec3 LightIntensity = vec3(0.0f);

    vec4 texDiffuseColor = texture2D(ColorSampler, TexCoords);
    vec3 normalDir = (gl_FrontFacing ? -Normal : Normal);

    for (int idx = 0; idx < LightCount; idx++)
    {
        vec3 lightDir = vec3(LightInfos[idx].Position) - Position.xyz;
        vec3 viewDir = -Position.xyz;

        float lightAttenuationFactor = getLightAttenuationFactor(lightDir, LightInfos[idx]);

        LightIntensity += Basic_Phong_Shading(
            -normalize(normalDir), normalize(lightDir), normalize(viewDir), idx
        ) * lightAttenuationFactor;
    }
    FragColor = vec4(LightIntensity, 1.0f) * texDiffuseColor;
}
```

Are you agree with me?

Comment: This question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233005/assigning-texture-to-an-object-using-multiple-textures.

Comment: Hello. This question is talking about multi texturing problem. For example Lara Croft can be mapped with a color map for the hard color of the character and to render some fakes reliefs on her we can use additionnal texture like normal maps or bump maps. This way I will have to use glActiveTexture twice and use these texture units in the fagment shader. But it's not my problem here (as I said above). All I want to know is the following question: Do I need 2 shader program instances to render a scene composed of 2 batches (1 rendered with 'texture_1' and the other with 'texture_2')?

Comment: I think so, because my fragment shader owns a unique uniform texture2d sampler declaration! (The goal of my shader program is to render geometry with a simple texture mapping plus ADS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible if you either: (i) consider it to be a multitexturing problem where the function per fragment just picks between the two incoming fragments (ideally using `mix` with a coefficient of `0.0` or `1.0`, not genuine branching); or (ii) composite your two textures into one texture (subject to your ability to wrap and clamp texture coordinates efficiently — watch out for those dependent reads — and maximum texture size constraints).

It's an open question as to whether either of these things would improve performance. Definitely go with (ii) if you can.